# Pandas cumsum results in NaN's even without missing values in Series

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, time-series

I have simple timeseries of returns that doesn't contain any NaN's. However, when I use `pandas.series.cumsum()` it returns NaN's for a large portion of the series. I'm not sure what would cause this behavior. Please advise!

```
log_returns = np.log(prices / prices.shift(1)).dropna()
```

[image: enter code here]

```
log_returns.cumsum()
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have `return=0.0` for some rows which leads to `-inf` log value?

Comment: That's the question I have. At what point is the value close enough to zero that Python\Pandas considers the `value==0.` resulting in a `-inf` log value? Is that a floating point issue?

Comment: @Alexander I tried your code and `log_returns[log_returns==np.nan]` both versions returned an empty series.

Comment: @Alexander it's the same operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**: It was a simple data issue. One of the price series had a day where price was equal to zero. Calculating log returns on a zero value produces `inf/-inf` which produces `NaN's` when calculating a rolling value.

I had to go detailed into the dataset to see what the issue was and found a couple `-inf` lurking in the series.

[image]

I altered my code to include the line:

```
cross_section = cross_section[np.isfinite(cross_section)]
```

and that got rid of the `-inf` and unexpected `NaN` in the dataset.

If anyone knows what would have caused this please chime in. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you're taking the log returns of the returns!? Should that be log returns of the prices? That would explain the `inf`s, since there must be returns with value zero.

Comment: No that was a typo. Definitely took the log returns of the price series. I updated my question to reflect it.

Comment: Do you have any zero prices?  log(0) = inf (or -inf)

Comment: @Alexander yes turns out there was a 0. value in one of the 3864 stock's price series. Now I'm trying to figure out how to delete a column if there are zero values in it programmatically.

Comment: I wouldn't delete the column.  Just ignore price points of zero.